# Should we delete this closed, cross-posted Spaceflight question and get rid of the Kerbal Space Program tag at the same time?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, specific-tag, scope

[Multiple aerobraking](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13669/7982) from 2016 was closed as off-topic but [the OP reposted the same question in Space SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14041/12102) before it could be migrated.

It was very well received there and has several good answers, including a clone of the answer here.

Since questions about heat shields for reentry are off-topic here and there's nothing here that's not also there in Space SE, I think this should just be removed.

Why?

1. While it is currently closed, there's always the danger of getting five re-open votes (which is one of the reasons why we stress *close/migration* over reposting)
2. The question is now attracting low-quality tags.[kerbal-space-program](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kerbal-space-program) has only three questions counting this one. In addition to deleting this post (ideally by first asking the answer author to delete their answer) we should also get rid of the rocket ship game tag. While [universe-sandbox](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universe-sandbox) can simulate and illustrate serious serious Astronomical phenomenon, the KSP game really can't. It's literally little green aliens flying around in models that keep fall apart and blowing up.

**Question:** Should we delete this closed, cross-posted Spaceflight question and get rid of the Kerbal Space Program tag at the same time?

Comment: I went ahead and removed it.

Comment: I've just gone ahead and removed the other two instances of the KSP tag.