# Are my comments being poorly received?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

Recently, I left a few comments on different posts, and received negative responses from other users. In the past, I have left the same kind of comment before, without any complications. So is there anything that I'm doing wrong, and what can I do to redeem myself?

Comment: What did the negative responses say? In what way were they insufficient in explaining what the concern was? I know I've left some from time to time and often (but not always) they relate to what I thought was being overly tough on new users. Here are a few that I've found;

Comment: [1](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/43336/#comment88381_43336), [2](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41936/#comment86212_41936), [3](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41258/#comment84452_41258), [4](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41018/#comment83821_41018), [5](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39877/#comment80799_39877) Different but related: [this question](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/726/7982) mentions the creation of the "rocket ship game tag" which seems off-topic in Astronomy SE.

Comment: @uhoh How do you put text over URL?

Comment: @User123 Use \[Text\](URL) in the Markdown.

Comment: @fasterthanlight [Thank you](https://www.littleoverlodge.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/hotel-derby-thank-you-2018-600x400.jpg)! I didn't know this before.

Comment: @fasterthanlight if you look at my posts, that's how I do it there as well. I only use inline links in my posts. I don't use the links at the bottom, i.e. [text][1] + [1]: url This makes it much easier to copy/paste a block of text from one post to another without worrying about all those links at the bottom and numbers conflicting. [some discussion here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1349/12102).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You weren't specific about the negative feedback, though uhoh's given some possible examples.  For myself, I like to periodically read the [closed questions guidance](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) and our [code of conduct](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/conduct) to remind myself what the site is about.  I also try not to vote or make decisions unless I am quite sure they are consistent with the linked guidance and precedent for the site.

I don't think you have to redeem yourself as I believe our community **doesn't hold grudges**!  I would suggest trying to use negative feedback to improve, if possible, **without being so hard on yourself**! I think you will continue to get positive feedback for thoughtful, helpful comments, especially on new users' posts.

Tomorrow will be another beautiful day on the stack exchange, so let's get out there and teach and learn some astronomy!

Comment: Me too, I every now and then close a question with the wrong (read: not fully thought-through) reasons, but I am thankful for careful observers (like @uhoh) to remind me if I did so.